# Как удалить элемент из списка?

Tags: c++

Проблема в следующем. Я создал программу, а точнее список, которая выводит элементы из файла нажатием на клавишу "а". Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы после выведенного элемента нажатием на "а", нажатием на "d" удалить поочередно последние выведенные элементы?

```
include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct el {
    string data;
    el *adres;
};
class List {
  private:
    el * fadr, *eadr;

  public:
    List() {
        fadr = NULL;
        eadr = NULL;
    } void fadd(string a) {
        el *v;
        v = new el;
        v->data = a;
        v->adres = fadr;
        fadr = v;
    }
    void print() {
        if (fadr == NULL) {
            cout << "List is emptyn";
            return;
        }
        el *v;
        for (v = fadr; v != NULL; v = v->adres)
            cout << v->data << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ifstream input("c:\f.txt");
    string s;

    while (!input.eof()) {
        char v = getch();
        if (v != 'a')
            continue;
        getline(input, s);
        cout << s << endl;

        if (v != 'd')
            continue;
        // Вот тут что писать, чтобы он убрал последний выведенный элемент?

    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @navi1893, Вам видимо после getch() надо делать что-то вроде

    switch(v) {
    case 'a': // get, add-to-list ...
        break;
    case 'd': // delete-from-list ...
        break:
    ....
    }

Comment: Да, но какой код нужен, чтобы удалить поочередно последне выведенные элементы?

Comment: Вы написали fadd() для списка. Напишите теперь fdel(). 

Если Вы хотите стереть текст с консоли, то можно позиционироваться в (заранее запомненную) позицию начала текста на экране и затереть текст пробелами, а потом опять переместить курсор в эту позицию.

Но, IMHO Вы на самом деле не думаете делать это. Или Вы текстовый редактор пишете ?

Comment: Нет, я бы хотел реализовать другой метод. Например я 3 раза нажал на "а", и там выводится на консоль 3 элемента, но при нажатии на "д" я хочу сделать clear screen и вывести заново n-1 элементов, т.е чтобы выдался 2 элемента на чистый экран

Comment: Ну, @navi1893, телепатия штука сложная. Задайте вопрос о windows clear screen.

Comment: я не хочу узнать как сделать clear screen, я хочу узнать как удалить последний элемент и вывести на чистый экран n-1 элементов

Comment: el \*v=fadr; if (v) {fadr=fadr->next; delete v; print(); }

Comment: а нельзя ли сделать как то вот так?

        char v = getch();
        if (v != 'a')
            continue;
        getline(input, s);
        cout << s << endl;
т.к я потом убрать хочу адреса из кода. Если возможно, то посоветуйте мне код соответствующий этому

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете стандартный контейнер `std::list`, то удаление последнего добавленного элемента из списка осуществляется методом `pop_back`, который вам надо добавить в обработчик нажатия на "d".

```
list<int> l;

l.push_back(0); // Добавили
l.pop_back(0); // Удалили
```

Comment: я вот код выложил и нужный комментарий. Можешь посмотреть и по нему уже сказать?
Написал: List.pop_back(); но выдает ошибки.

Comment: Вы в main даже список не создаете, как Вы что-то можете выводить?

Comment: @fogbit он из файла их достает, заметьте там
 ifstream input("c:\f.txt");

Comment: @navi1893 из файла там строки читаются и ни в какой список не кладутся. Определитесь точнее что именно Вам нужно: чтобы строка не доставлялась в список или чтобы выведенная на консоль строка была удалена из консоли по нажатию 'd'?

Comment: чтобы выведенная на консоль строка была удалена из консоли по нажатию 'd', это нужно

Comment: @navi1893, у меня лимит комментариев (тех под Вашим вопросом) закончился. Придется Вам самому додумывать (или просить ХэшКод об отмене лимитов или создании специального раздела для безлимитного общения).

---

По сути. *"а нельзя ли сделать как то вот так?"* можно **почти** все. Некоторые вещи просто делать удобнее определенным способом.

За основу возьмите switch() внутри while(). Код с fadr=fadr->next, естественно, (думал, что это очевидно) поместите в метод fdel(), который Вам предстоит написать.

Успехов.

P.S.

Про clear screen советую раскрутить самому (через Google).